# hibernate unnecceessary updates because of dirty checking

Tags: java, hibernate

I am reading the book Hibernate in Action (latest Early edition).
I came across "In order to avoid unnecessary updates in dirty checking in the case of string or any other object other than collections, new instances need to be created
--page 30 of the early edition book

```
 public String getitem(){
 return new String(this.itemvalue); }
```

please explain in detail the need behind this behaviour

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to me. Copying a String is useless. Could you provide more context?

Comment: My assumption was wrong.Got a reply from the book author Christian Bauer.He says "Nowhere does it say "in order to avoid". It says that even if you do this, it's ok. Obviously you shouldn't do this.."